# I am trying to unwrap?, explode?, a data frame with several columns into a new data frame with rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I apologize for not knowing the correct terminology, but I am looking for a way in Pandas to transform a data frame with several similar columns into a data frame with rows that explode? into more rows.  Basically for every column that starts with Line.{x}, I want to create a new row that has all the Line.{x} columns.  Same for all columns with values in {x}, e.g. 1,2,3.

Here is an example of a data frame I'd like to convert from:

```
                    Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4      Line.0.a       Line.0.b    Line.0.c     Line.1.a       Line.1.b    Line.1.c     Line.2.a       Line.2.b    Line.2.c      Line.3.a       Line.3.b       Line.3.c
        0           the         quick       brown       dog          100               200           300        400             500          600       700              800        900           1000           1100          1200
        1           you         see         spot        run          101               201           301        401             501          601
        2           four        score       and         seven        102               202           302
```

I would like to convert it to this:

```
        Column1     Column2   Column3      Column4         Line.a           Line.b      Line.c
0          the       quick    brown        dog             100              200         300             
1          the       quick    brown        dog             400              500         600             
2          the       quick    brown        dog             700              800         900
3          the       quick    brown        dog            1000             1100        1200
4          you       see      spot         run             101              201         301 
5          you       see      spot         run             401              501         601
6          four      score    and          seven           102              202         302
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Create a MultiIndex with the extracted value from the `x.VALUE.x` columns and `stack`

Comment: You are looking for melt method

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that works. It uses melt and then joins.
new_df contains what you need. the order of items might be different though.  The fuction takes 3 parameters. The first is your data frame. Second is keys that remain static and third is convertion dict that tells what goes where.

```
import pandas as pd

def vars_to_cases(df:pd.DataFrame,keys:list,convertion_dict:dict):
    vals = list(convertion_dict.values())
    l = len(vals[0])
    if not all(len(item) == l for item in vals):
        raise Exception("Dictionary values don't have the same length")
    tempkeys = keys.copy()
    tempkeys.append("variable")
    df_data = pd.DataFrame()
    for short_name, my_list in convertion_dict.items():
        my_replace_dict = {}
        for count, item, in enumerate(my_list):
            my_replace_dict[item] = count

        mydf = pd.melt(df, id_vars=tempkeys[:-1], value_vars=my_list)

        mydf["variable"].replace(my_replace_dict, inplace=True)
        mydf.rename(columns={"value": short_name}, inplace=True)
        mydf = mydf.set_index(tempkeys)
        if df_data.empty:
            df_data = mydf.copy()
        else:
            df_data = df_data.join(mydf)
    return df_data

#here is the data
df=pd.DataFrame({'Column1': {0: 'the', 1: 'you', 2: 'four'},
             'Column2': {0: 'quick', 1: 'see', 2: 'score'},
             'Column3': {0: 'brown', 1: 'spot', 2: 'and'},
             'Column4': {0: 'dog', 1: 'run', 2: 'seven'},
             'Line.0.a': {0: 100, 1: 101, 2: 102},
             'Line.0.b': {0: 200, 1: 201, 2: 202},
             'Line.0.c': {0: 300, 1: 301, 2: 302},
             'Line.1.a': {0: 400.0, 1: 401.0, 2: None},
             'Line.1.b': {0: 500.0, 1: 501.0, 2: None},
             'Line.1.c': {0: 600.0, 1: 601.0, 2: None},
             'Line.2.a': {0: 700.0, 1: None, 2: None},
             'Line.2.b': {0: 800.0, 1: None, 2: None},
             'Line.2.c': {0: 900.0, 1: None, 2: None},
             'Line.3.a': {0: 1000.0, 1: None, 2: None},
             'Line.3.b': {0: 1100.0, 1: None, 2: None},
             'Line.3.c': {0: 1200.0, 1: None, 2: None}})



convertion_dict={"Line.a":["Line.0.a","Line.1.a","Line.2.a","Line.3.a"],
                 "Line.b":["Line.0.b","Line.1.b","Line.2.b","Line.3.b"],
                 "Line.c":["Line.0.c","Line.1.c","Line.2.c","Line.3.c"]}

keys=["Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4"]

new_df=vars_to_cases(df,keys,convertion_dict)
new_df=new_df.reset_index()
new_df=new_df.dropna()
new_df=new_df.drop(columns="variable")
```

Comment: Thanks Atanas.  As you mentioned, I am trying to do this programmatically.  I am using your solution above, however, as it turns out, not all of my convertion_dict items are of the same length.  I am stumped on how to handle this?  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Stockmage for a fast solution I would just add empty columns in the input data-frame and then put the empty col names in the conversion dict's list so that all lengths match. It is not an ideal way but it should work

Comment: what I mean is if we imagine that your sample dataframe was missing the column "Line.3.a" then add it first 
i.e. df["Line.3.a"]=None
Before running the vars_to_cases function

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), where for this particular use case, you pass `.value` placeholder to `names_to`, to keep track of the parts of the column you want to retain as headers; you then pass a regular expression with matching groups to `names_pattern`:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(index='Col*', 
                names_to = (".value", ".value"), 
                names_pattern = r"(.+)\.\d+(.+)") 
   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4  Line.a  Line.b  Line.c
0      the   quick   brown     dog   100.0   200.0   300.0
1      you     see    spot     run   101.0   201.0   301.0
2     four   score     and   seven   102.0   202.0   302.0
3      the   quick   brown     dog   400.0   500.0   600.0
4      you     see    spot     run   401.0   501.0   601.0
5     four   score     and   seven     NaN     NaN     NaN
6      the   quick   brown     dog   700.0   800.0   900.0
7      you     see    spot     run     NaN     NaN     NaN
8     four   score     and   seven     NaN     NaN     NaN
9      the   quick   brown     dog  1000.0  1100.0  1200.0
10     you     see    spot     run     NaN     NaN     NaN
11    four   score     and   seven     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

You can get rid of the nulls with `dropna`:

```py
(df
.pivot_longer(
    index='Col*', 
    names_to = (".value", ".value"), 
    names_pattern = r"(.+)\.\d+(.+)")
.dropna()
)

  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4  Line.a  Line.b  Line.c
0     the   quick   brown     dog   100.0   200.0   300.0
1     you     see    spot     run   101.0   201.0   301.0
2    four   score     and   seven   102.0   202.0   302.0
3     the   quick   brown     dog   400.0   500.0   600.0
4     you     see    spot     run   401.0   501.0   601.0
6     the   quick   brown     dog   700.0   800.0   900.0
9     the   quick   brown     dog  1000.0  1100.0  1200.0
```

Another option, as pointed out by @Mozway, is to convert the columns into a MultiIndex, and stack:

```py
temp = df.set_index(['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3','Column4'])
# this is where the MultiIndex is created
cols = temp.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
temp.columns = cols
# now we stack
# nulls are dropped by default
temp = temp.stack(level=1).droplevel(-1)
temp.columns = temp.columns.map('.'.join)
temp.reset_index()

  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4  Line.a  Line.b  Line.c
0     the   quick   brown     dog   100.0   200.0   300.0
1     the   quick   brown     dog   400.0   500.0   600.0
2     the   quick   brown     dog   700.0   800.0   900.0
3     the   quick   brown     dog  1000.0  1100.0  1200.0
4     you     see    spot     run   101.0   201.0   301.0
5     you     see    spot     run   401.0   501.0   601.0
6    four   score     and   seven   102.0   202.0   302.0
```

Comment: Still I like my approach better as in both solutions you provide you rely on 1 regular expressions to be able to catch a pattern or 2 str.split. my approach works with arbitrary columns names. you need to specify them in a dict.